# svg animate rectangle using jquery animate

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-animate, jquery-svg

Please refer below column chart image.

[image]

**how can i make the animation in svg rectangle. for positive value it will growing upwards and for negative value growing downwards.**

1. I want to do this using jquery animate. i have implemented something
   increasing the height of rect. its fine for negative value but for
   positive value need to start for origin y axis value 0 and goes
   upwards. but it animating reverse order. i don't know what's going
   wrong. please refer my code snippet.

========================================================================

```
$(element).animate(
            {
                y: parseFloat($(element).attr("y")),
                height: parseFloat($(element).attr("height"))
            },
            {
                duration: 2000,

                step: function(now, fx) {
                    if (fx.prop == "y") {
                        $(element).attr("y", -now);
                    } else
                        $(element).attr("height", now);

                }
            });






<g id="container_svg_SeriesGroup_0" transform="translate(82,463)"><defs><linearGradient id="container_svg_series_0Gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%"><stop offset="0" stop-color="gray" stop-opacity="1"/><stop offset="0.5" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="1"/></linearGradient></defs><rect id="container_svg_Point0" x="104.7" y="-270.72222222222223" width="44.41818181818182" height="24.61111111111111" fill="url(#container_svg_series_0Gradient)" stroke-width="1" stroke="Gray" style="display: inline-block; height: 24.6111px;" transform="scale(1,0.4)"/><rect id="container_svg_Point1" x="168.15454545454546" y="-246.1111111111111" width="44.418181818181836" height="73.83333333333333" fill="url(#container_svg_series_0Gradient)" stroke-width="1" stroke="Gray" style="display: inline-block; height: 73.8333px;"/><rect id="container_svg_Point2" x="231.6090909090909" y="-283.02777777777777" width="44.41818181818181" height="36.916666666666664" fill="url(#container_svg_series_0Gradient)" stroke-width="1" stroke="Gray" style="display: inline-block; height: 36.9167px;"/><rect id="container_svg_Point3" x="295.0636363636364" y="-406.08333333333337" width="44.41818181818172" height="159.97222222222223" fill="url(#container_svg_series_0Gradient)" stroke-width="1" stroke="Gray" style="display: inline-block; height: 159.972px;"/><rect id="container_svg_Point4" x="358.51818181818186" y="-246.11111111111111" width="44.41818181818178" height="221.5" fill="url(#container_svg_series_0Gradient)" stroke-width="1" stroke="Gray" style="display: inline-block; height: 221.5px;"/></g>
```

---

Comment: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform

Comment: i dont want to use custom plugin. i want to do using jquery.animate only

Answer (score 3):

When the value is positive you need to also change the y position of the rectangle. Something like:

```
step: function(now, fx) {
    if (!isNaN(now)) {
        $(element).attr("y", -now);
        $(element).attr("height", now);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I think this will work for you:

```
        var elements = $("#container_svg_SeriesGroup_0 rect");

        for (var e=0; e<elements.length; e++) {
            var $element = $(elements[e]);
            var height = parseFloat($element.attr("height"));
            var y = parseFloat($element.attr("y"));

            if (y < -247) {
                $element.animate( { height: height },
                {
                    duration: 2000,
                    step: function(now, fx) {
                        if(!isNaN(now)) {
                            $(this).attr("y", -247-now);
                            $(this).attr("height", now);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $element.animate( { height: height },
                {
                    duration: 2000,
                    step: function(now, fx) {
                        if(!isNaN(now)) {
                            $(this).attr("height", now);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but in your code shows "top" value.in your description u mentioned about "y" value.confusing.could you please more clear ?

Comment: I thought you were using div. If you're using rects then use "y" instead of "top".

Comment: y axis css position are from "top" or "bottom"

Comment: thanks. but now rectangle is not showing after using your code why ? due to modifying the rectangle y value. please see my updated code snippet

Comment: The problem might be that SVG does not allow negative heights. It might be easier if you show me the SVG you are using.

Comment: OK, I think the issue is that your 0 line is not at y=0 it's at y=217. If you change the code to `$(element).attr("y", 217-now);` it might work.